# positioning divs with css sprites: is there a way to auto vertical-center for a neater result

Tags: jquery, css, alignment, sprite

[jsfiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/CGcdc/)

Click a county name to see it's crest appear.

I am appending divs as they are needed and the background for each div is from a css sprite which works perfectly. What I would like is to vertical center each added div so they line up more neatly.

I can add `position: relative; top: XXpx;` and amend the top manually for each each crest e.g.`.Corksmall { background-position:  -25px -27px; height: 27px; width: 25px; position: relative; top: 5px;}` but that seems like the brute force method.

Is there a more coder pleasing way of doing this? tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple trick to achieve this behavior.

```
#selectedCounties .sprite-smallcrests {
    /* float: left; */ /* removed. no need for, because we apply display: inline-block */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/CGcdc/4/

You may have noticed, that the pictures/`div`s jump, depending on the height of each picture.
Prepending an empty element with a height of the tallest picture possible, will prevent the jumping:
**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/CGcdc/9/

If you want to get this crossbrowser compatible, replace the wrapper `div`s with `span`s or other elements which are inline-elements by default:

```
$('#Clare, #Cork, #Limerick').click(function(){
    $('<span/>', {
        title: 'Co. '+this.id,
        'class': this.id+'small sprite-smallcrests'
    }).appendTo('#selectedCounties');
});
```

Hope this will fix your problem :)

Comment: @Chris To make this a little more backwards compatible as far as IE is concerned. http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/ If you find it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding,you want to center the `smallcrests`.. so,try this.. change the following css to the given below.

```
#selectedCounties .sprite-smallcrests {
margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CGcdc/2/)

Comment: sorry, I should have explained better:
I want the crest to appear horizontally, and the center of each crest would seem to sit along the same horizontal line.
The end result I would like is **http://jsfiddle.net/CGcdc/3/**
In this example I manually amended each `top` and I would like a way to go this automatically.

Comment: what do you mean automatic ?.. if you want them to be aligned - you need to do it with CSS - using the class itself..

Comment: hi, I often use the wrong phrase. I'm still very much a noob. If you check my accepted answer above you'll see what I was looking for. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is save each image with the same exact height and position the crest's vertically in the image document.

In your case with the sprite sheet this means: Just leave enough space vertically so that you can set one static height to all of the images.

Explanatory image.

[image]

- Green area is the image of the crest.
- Red border is the whole image.
- White space represents the empty space you would leave in each img document ( or padding between crests in your sprite sheet. )

Comment: Thanks for you idea. I'm sure I'll use this in the future. The accepted answer above gives me what I wanted in this instance.